# Changing menu content of master page from child page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

Here is the section of my master page file in ASP.NET.

```
<body>
      <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="inbox.aspx">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="comp.aspx">Compose</a></li>
        <li><a href="Sent.aspx">Sent</a></li>
      </ul>

    .......
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Now when i create a child page only the contentplaceholder is available to make changes but i want to change the class="active" from 1st li tag of Inbox to that of compose li tag.That is i would like to access this Master Page li tag in child page and assign child different values for each child page.

Comment: where u want to change css on client side or server side

Answer (score 0):

You can make that tag a server side tag in the master page by adding the attribute 
`runat='server'` and giving it an id value `id='someID'`.

In the code behind you can get it by:

```
Master.FindControl("someID")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0(v=vs.100).aspx